# xml -tag warning in android

Tags: android, xml, layout, textview

I am a newbie to android ....I get the following warning for using a text view ..I don't understand its purpose .. can any1 explain please?

Warning:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  //warning1
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="82dp"       //warning2
        android:layout_marginTop="93dp"
        android:text="@string/Test" />
```

**warning1**
Consider adding android:layout_marginStart="82dp" to better support right-to-left layouts
Issue: Looks for hardcoded left/right constants which could be start/end for bidirectional text
Id: RtlHardcoded

**warning2**
Consider adding android:layout_alignParentStart="true" to better support right-to-left layouts
Issue: Looks for hardcoded left/right constants which could be start/end for bidirectional text
Id: RtlHardcoded

Comment: **1** These aren't errors, just warnings (so, not to be considered harmful). **2** To get rid of them, just add the suggested lines.

Comment: suggested lines means?  Can you explain?

Comment: Nothing, just a new way to complain... ;) Ok, it's for better supporting RTL languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore warnings 
Or if u dnt need to get those auto generated margins  you should use linear layout before dragging views to layout

Comment: is there anyway to clear the warning with the relative layout?

Comment: Follow the suggestion of the warning. You can clear them .every string value or constant should not be given directly in layout xml file if you need to remove the warnings. That means the values you are giving should be declared in values folder